# Como cargo datos a un comboBox segun el item seleccionado en el comboBox principal usando solo enumarados.JAVA

Tags: java, combobox, enum

La cosa es asi, yo tengo un comboBox general llamado JComboBox comboSubGrupos y un combo Box principal que es JComboBox comboTipoIndustria.

Mi JComboBox comboTipoIndustria carga los datos de TipoIndustria.enum

Lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que seleccione un index de mi enumerado TipoIndustria en mi comboTipoIndustria,  se cargue en comboSubGrupos  la información del enumerado TipoIndustria19SubGrupos.enum y sino se cargue otro enumerado llamado TipoIndustria1SubGrupos.enum

Tambeien les dejo como cree mis comboBox, es una forma mas prolija de hacerlo.

Esto no lo he podido hacer por mas que lo intente.

```
public class VentanaEmpresa extends JInternalFrame implements IVentanaEmpresa {

    private TipoIndustria tipoIndustria;
    private TipoIndustria19SubGrupos tipoIndustria19SubGrupos;

    private JTextField txtRazonSocial;
    private JTextField txtDireccion;
    private JTextField txtLocalidad;
    private JTextField txtRuc;
    private JTextField txtLocal;

    private JLabel lblDatosGeneralesDe;
    private JLabel lblRazonSocial;
    private JLabel lblRuc;
    private JLabel lblDireccion;
    private JLabel lblTipoIndustria;
    private JLabel lblSubGrupo;
    private JLabel lblLocal;
    private JLabel lblLocalidad;

    private JComboBox comboSubGrupos;
    private ComboTipoIndustria comboTipoIndustria;
    private ComboTipoIndustria19SubGrupos comboTipoIndustria19SubGrupos;
    private ComboTipoIndustria1SubGrupos comboSubGrupoTipoIndustria1;

    private JButton btnGuardar;
    private JButton btnSalir;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    VentanaEmpresa frame = new VentanaEmpresa();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public VentanaEmpresa() {
        setTitle("EMPRESA");
        setBounds(100, 100, 772, 356);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        getContentPane().add(getLblDatos());
        getContentPane().add(getLblRazonSocial());
        getContentPane().add(getLblRazonSocial());
        getContentPane().add(getLblRuc());
        getContentPane().add(getLblDireccion());
        getContentPane().add(getLblTipoIndustria());
        getContentPane().add(getLblSubGrupo());
        getContentPane().add(getLblLocal());
        getContentPane().add(getLblLocalidad());

        getContentPane().add(getComboSubGrupos());
        getContentPane().add(getComboTipoIndustria());

        getContentPane().add(getTxtLocalidad());
        getContentPane().add(getTxtRazonSocial());
        getContentPane().add(getTxtDireccion());
        getContentPane().add(getTxtRuc());
        getContentPane().add(getTxtLocal());

        getContentPane().add(getBtnGuardar());
        getContentPane().add(getBtnSalir());

    }

    private JLabel getLblDatos() {
        if (lblDatosGeneralesDe == null) {
            lblDatosGeneralesDe = new JLabel("DATOS GENERALES DE LA EMPRESA");
            lblDatosGeneralesDe.setBounds(279, 11, 191, 21);
        }
        return lblDatosGeneralesDe;
    }

    private JLabel getLblRazonSocial() {
        if (lblRazonSocial == null) {
            lblRazonSocial = new JLabel("RAZON SOCIAL:");
            lblRazonSocial.setBounds(10, 58, 90, 21);

        }

        return lblRazonSocial;
    }

    private JLabel getLblRuc() {
        if (lblRuc == null) {
            lblRuc = new JLabel("RUC:");
            lblRuc.setBounds(400, 58, 70, 21);

        }

        return lblRuc;
    }

    private JLabel getLblDireccion() {
        if (lblDireccion == null) {
            lblDireccion = new JLabel("DIRECCION:");
            lblDireccion.setBounds(10, 159, 90, 21);

        }
        return lblDireccion;
    }

    private JLabel getLblTipoIndustria() {
        if (lblTipoIndustria == null) {
            lblTipoIndustria = new JLabel("TIPO INDUSTRIA:");
            lblTipoIndustria.setBounds(10, 211, 100, 21);

        }
        return lblTipoIndustria;
    }

    private ComboTipoIndustria getComboTipoIndustria() {
        if (comboTipoIndustria == null) {
            comboTipoIndustria = new ComboTipoIndustria();
            comboTipoIndustria.setBounds(120, 212, 223, 20);
        }
        return comboTipoIndustria;
    }

    private ComboTipoIndustria19SubGrupos getComboTipoIndustria19SubGrupos() {
        if (comboTipoIndustria19SubGrupos == null) {
            comboTipoIndustria19SubGrupos = new ComboTipoIndustria19SubGrupos();
        }
        return comboTipoIndustria19SubGrupos;
    }

    private JComboBox getComboSubGrupos() {
        if (comboSubGrupos == null) {
            comboSubGrupos = new JComboBox();
            comboSubGrupos.setBounds(482, 211, 166, 21);
            comboSubGrupos.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (getComboTipoIndustria()
                            .getTipoIndustriaItemSeleccionado() == TipoIndustria.SERVICIOS_PROFESIONALES) {
                        comboSubGrupos = new ComboTipoIndustria19SubGrupos();
                    } else {
                        comboSubGrupos = new JComboBox();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        return comboSubGrupos;
    }

    private JLabel getLblSubGrupo() {
        if (lblSubGrupo == null) {
            lblSubGrupo = new JLabel("SUBGRUPO:");
            lblSubGrupo.setBounds(400, 211, 70, 21);

        }
        return lblSubGrupo;
    }

    private JLabel getLblLocal() {
        if (lblLocal == null) {
            lblLocal = new JLabel("LOCAL:");
            lblLocal.setBounds(400, 113, 58, 21);

        }
        return lblLocal;
    }

    private JLabel getLblLocalidad() {
        if (lblLocalidad == null) {
            lblLocalidad = new JLabel("LOCALIDAD:");
            lblLocalidad.setBounds(10, 109, 90, 21);

        }
        return lblLocalidad;
    }

    private JTextField getTxtRazonSocial() {
        if (txtRazonSocial == null) {
            txtRazonSocial = new JTextField();
            txtRazonSocial.setBounds(120, 58, 223, 20);
            txtRazonSocial.setColumns(10);
        }
        return txtRazonSocial;
    }

    private JTextField getTxtDireccion() {
        if (txtDireccion == null) {
            txtDireccion = new JTextField();
            txtDireccion.setBounds(120, 159, 223, 20);
            txtDireccion.setColumns(10);
        }
        return txtDireccion;
    }

    private JTextField getTxtLocalidad() {
        if (txtLocalidad == null) {
            txtLocalidad = new JTextField();
            txtLocalidad.setBounds(120, 109, 223, 20);
            txtLocalidad.setColumns(10);
        }
        return txtLocalidad;
    }

    private JTextField getTxtRuc() {
        if (txtRuc == null) {
            txtRuc = new JTextField();
            txtRuc.setColumns(10);
            txtRuc.setBounds(480, 58, 223, 20);

        }
        return txtRuc;
    }

    private JTextField getTxtLocal() {
        if (txtLocal == null) {
            txtLocal = new JTextField();
            txtLocal.setColumns(10);
            txtLocal.setBounds(480, 113, 70, 20);

        }
        return txtLocal;
    }

    private JButton getBtnGuardar() {
        if (btnGuardar == null) {
            btnGuardar = new JButton("GUARDAR");
            btnGuardar.setBounds(254, 292, 89, 23);

        }
        return btnGuardar;
    }

    private JButton getBtnSalir() {
        if (btnSalir == null) {
            btnSalir = new JButton("SALIR");
            btnSalir.setBounds(400, 292, 89, 23);

        }
        return btnSalir;
    }

    // getters for IGUI

    public TipoIndustria getTipoIndustria() {
        return getComboTipoIndustria().getTipoIndustriaItemSeleccionado();
    }

    public TipoIndustria19SubGrupos getTipoIndustria19SubGrupos() {
        return getComboTipoIndustria19SubGrupos().getTipoIndustria19SubGrupoItemSeleccionado();
    }

}

public enum TipoIndustria {

    PROCESAMIENTO_CONSERVACION_DE_ALIMENTOS_BEBIDAS_TABACO("Procesamiento y Conservacíon de alimentos, bebida y tabaco",
            1),
    INDUSTRIA_FRIGORIFICO("Industria frigorífico", 2), PESCA("Pesca", 3), INDUSTRIA_TEXTIL("Industra Textil", 4),
    INDUSTRIA_CUERO_VESTIMENTA_CALZADO("Industrias del Cuero, Vestimenta y Calzado", 5),
    INDUSTRIA_MADERA_CELULOSA_PAPEL("Industria de la Madera, celulosa y papel", 6),
    INDUSTRIA_QUIMICA_FARMACEUTICA("Industria química, del medicamento, farmacéutica, de combustibles y anexos", 7),
    INDUSTRIA_PRUDCTOS_METALICOS_MAQUINARIA_EQUIPO("Industria de productos metálicos, maquinarias y equipo", 8),
    INDUSTRIA_CONSTRUCCION("Industria de la construcción y actividades complementarias", 9),
    COMERCIO_GENERAL("Comercio en general", 10), COMERCIO_MINORISTA("Comercio minorista de la alimentación", 11),
    COMERCIO_MINORISTA_ALIMENTACION("Hoteles, restoranes y bares", 12),
    HOTELES_RESTORANES_BARES("Transporte y almacenamiento", 13),
    TRANSPORTE_Y_ALMACENAMIENTO("Intermediación financiera, seguros y pensiones", 14),
    INTERMEDIACION_FINANCIERA("Servicios de salud y anexos", 15),
    SERVICIOS_SALUD_ENSENIANZA("Servicios de enseñanza", 16), INDUSTRIA_GRAFICA("Industria gráfica", 17),
    SERVICIOS_CULTURALES("Servicios culturales, de esparcimiento y comunicaciones", 18),
    SERVICIOS_PROFESIONALES("Servicios profesionales, técnicos, especializados y aquellos no incluidos en otros grupos",
            19),
    ENTIDADES_GREMIALES("Entidades gremiales, sociales y deportivas", 20), SERVICIO_DOMESTICO("Servicio doméstico", 21),
    GANADERIA("Ganadería, Agricultura y actividades conexas", 22),
    VINIEDOS_FRUTICULTURA(
            "Viñedos, fruticultura, horticultura, floricultura, criaderos de aves, suinos, apicultura y otras actividades",
            23),
    FORESTACION("Forestación (incluído bosques, montes y turberas)", 24);

    private String texto;
    private double grupo; 

    private TipoIndustria(String texto, double grupo) {
        this.texto = texto;
        this.grupo = grupo;
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return this.texto;
    }

    public double getGrupo() {
        return this.grupo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return texto;
    }
}


public enum TipoIndustria1SubGrupos {

    INDUSTRIA_LACTEA("Industria Láctea",1.1),
    DISTRIUBUIDORES_PRODUCTOS_LACTEOS("Distribuidores de Productos Lácteos",1.2),
    HELADERIAS_INDUSTRIALES("Heladerías industriales",1.3),
    EMPAQUE_ENVASADO_FRUTAS_LEGUMBRES("Empaque y envasado de frutas, legumbres y hortalizas",2),
    PRODUCCION_HIELO_CAMARAS_FRIO("Producción de hielo y cámaras de frío",3),
    INDUSTRIA_AZUCARERA("Industria azucarera",4),
    MOLINOS_ARROZ("Molinos de arroz",5),
    MOLINOS_DE_TRIGO_HARINAS_FECULAS("Molinos de trigo, harinas, féculas, sal y fábri", 6),
    MOLINOS_DE_TRIGO("Molinos de Trigo",6.1),
    FABRICA_RACIONES("Fábrica de raciones balanceadas",6.2),
    MOLINOS_DE_SAL("Molinos de sal",6.3),
    DULCES_CHOCOLATES_GOLOS("Dulces, chocolates, golosinas, galletitas y alf",7),
    DULCES_CHOCOLATES_GOLOS_GALL("Dulces, chocolates, golosinas, galletitas y alf",7.1),
    FIDEERIAS("Fideerías",7.2),
    PANIFICADORAS_INDUSTRIALES("Panificadoras Industriales",7.3),
    MOLINDOS_DE_YERBA("Molinos de Yerba",7.4),
    MOLINOS_DE_CAFE("Molinos de café y té",7.5),
    ACEITRAS_VEGETAL_ANIMAL("Aceiteras de origen animal o vegetal para uso h",8),
    ACEITERAS("Aceiteras",8.1),
    GRASAS_MARGARINAS("Grasas y margarinas",8.2),
    BEBIDAS_SIN_ALCOHOL_CERVEZAS("Bebidas sin alcohol y cervezas",9.1),
    MALTERIAS("Malterías",9.2),
    LICORERIAS("Licorerías",10),
    BODEGAS("Bodegas",11),
    FABRICACION_HELADOS_PANADERIAS_CON_PLANTA_ELABORACION("Fabricación de helados, panaderías y con plantas de elaboración",12),
    PANADERIAS_CONFITERIAS_PLANTA_DE_ELABORACION("Panaderías y confiterías con planta de elaboración",12.1),
    FABRICA_PASTAS("Fábricas de Pastas",12.2),
    CATERING_INDUSTRIAL("Catering industrial",12.3),
    TABACOS_CIGARRILLOS("Tabacos y cigarrillos",13),
    TABACOS_Y_CIGARRILLOS("Tabacos y cigarrillos",13.1),
    PLANTAS_DE_ACOPIO("Plantas de acopio y proc. de hojas de tabaco",13.2);





    private String texto;
    private double subGrupo;

    private TipoIndustria1SubGrupos(String texto, double subGrupo) {
        this.texto = texto;
        this.subGrupo = subGrupo;

    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return this.texto;
    }

    public double getSubGrupo() {
        return this.subGrupo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return texto;
    }

}

public enum TipoIndustria19SubGrupos {

    DESPACHANTE_ADUANA("Despachantes de Aduana",1),
    EMPRESAS_SUMINISTRADORAS_MANO_OBRA("Personal de edificios de Propiedad Horizontal",2),
    PERSONAL_EDIFICIOS_PROPIEDAD_HORIZONTAL("Informatica",3),
    INFORMATICA("Empresas suministradoras de mano de obra",22);


    private String texto;
    private double subGrupo;

    private TipoIndustria19SubGrupos(String texto, double subGrupo) {
        this.texto = texto;
        this.subGrupo = subGrupo;
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return this.texto;
    }

    public double getSubGrupo() {
        return this.subGrupo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return texto;
    }

}

public class ComboTipoIndustria1SubGrupos extends JComboBox {

    public ComboTipoIndustria1SubGrupos() {
        super();
        inicializar();
    }

    public void inicializar() {
        for (TipoIndustria1SubGrupos t : TipoIndustria1SubGrupos.values()) {
            this.addItem(t);
        }
    }

    public TipoIndustria1SubGrupos getTipoIndustria1SubGrupos(int index) {
        return (TipoIndustria1SubGrupos) getItemAt(index);
    }

    public TipoIndustria1SubGrupos getTipoIndustria1SubGrupoItemSeleccionado() {
        return getTipoIndustria1SubGrupos(getSelectedIndex());
    }

    public void setTipoIndustria1SubGruposItemSeleccionado(TipoIndustria1SubGrupos tipo) {
        for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
            TipoIndustria1SubGrupos item = (TipoIndustria1SubGrupos) getItemAt(i);
            if (item.equals(tipo)) {
                setSelectedIndex(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No pusiste el código que realmente interesa para ayudar y pusiste mucho código que ni siquiera esta relacionado.

Comment: que código faltaría? O que es mejor que agregue? @abrahamhs

Comment: ¿Por qué *singleton* para etiquetas?